# XPath Help - Code for getting data before "<br>" Tag

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

So here is what I want to do to start off here is a simple sample HTML code

```
<html>
<body>
  <b>This a test <br>ABCD</b>
</body>
</html>
```

So now how can I get only the text "`This a test`"
I tried to do something like this "`/html/body/b`" but I get "`ABCD`" as the output? What can I do to get "`This is a test`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression could be:-

```
/html/body/b[1]
```

This may provide you the string "`This a test`".

Hope it helps.

Comment: According to the HTML, it may be "`/html/body/div/div[2]/div[@id='content']/div/div[1]`". This may list you the duration of all the songs listed in that page.

Comment: Please post the full text which is being fetched by this XPath.

Comment: Please try these one by one: "`/html/body/div/div[2]/div[@id='content']/div/div[0]`", "`/html/body/div/div[2]/div[@id='content']/div/div[position()<1]`", "`/html/body/div/div[2]/div[@id='content']/div/div[position()<2]`".